# PHP cron fwrite dont work

Tags: php, cron

I try this:

```
<?php
$time = time();
$fh = fopen("cron.txt", 'a+');
fwrite($fh, $time);
echo "ok";
?>
```

to run on SSH:

```
/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/cron.php
```

and remote server:

```
budzinski.xyz/cron.php
```

on localhost it works fine, on remote server and on cron, don't

Comment: is it shared hosting, do they have allow_url_fopen disabled? http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php, "You can only use fopen() to access remote files if fopen wrappers is enabled. This parameter is specified in the php.ini file and cannot be changed at run time using ini_set"

Comment: Is there any information about the error?

Comment: is self configured bitnami server on AWS and on php.ini it has:

allow_url_fopen = On
it's shows no errors

Comment: I think this should be asked on different StackExchange forum as I reckon it's more to do with server/cron than coding.

Comment: The problem is likely the *current working directory*, relative to which `cron.txt` will be resolved. You likely don't have write permissions in that directory. **Use an absolute path** to avoid problems of ambiguous file names.

Comment: I changed it to: /home/bitnami/htdocs/cron.php but this cron.php dont work even by url

Comment: anyone interested in help?

Answer (score 0):

your cron command needs to modified like this-:

```
  /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /home/[yourcpanelname]/[your patht to the file]/cron.php
```

Comment: ok i changed it to: /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /home/bitnami/htdocs/cron.php you think php directory can be bad too?

Answer (score 0):

check the permissions of file is it writable  or not 
Try out this example and than see if you are getting any output or not

```
<?php
 $filename = 'test.txt';
 $somecontent = "Add this to the file\n";

// Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
  if (is_writable($filename)) {

// In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
// The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
// that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it.
if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
     echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
     exit;
}

// Write $somecontent to our opened file.
if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
    exit;
}

echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";

fclose($handle);

  } else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Success, wrote (Add this to the file ) to file (cron.txt) but still my cron dont work

Comment: try to open file with mode a and not a+ like this -: fopen($filename, 'a')

Comment: still dont work via SSH and cron but by url @hamza-dairywala

Comment: okay than set your cron with the curl command like this -: curl --slient http:://[site url path]/cron.php